# CAS Authentication failed! Wamp Server 3.0.6

Tags: php, tomcat, wamp, single-sign-on, cas

I am using:
- Wamp Server 3.0.6
- apache 2.4.23
- php 5.4.45
- mysql 5.5.53
My Php application calls my local CAS server (tomcat 8 with Cas 3.6.0) to authenticate the useres.

The config files are too long to post here but I changed my cas.properties to:

```
    server.name=http://localhost:8081
    server.prefix=${server.name}/cas-server-webapp-3.6.0
```

And changed all https:// references either in app code or configs from both sides to http://.

When I test the connexion I get the following error:

```
CAS Authentication failed!
You were not authenticated.

You may submit your request again by clicking here.

If the problem persists, you may contact the administrator of this site.

<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
    <cas:authenticationFailure code='INVALID_TICKET'>
        le ticket  ;ST-4-sD6KXe3YbdG4qp9FwT01-cas01.example.org ; est inconnu
    </cas:authenticationFailure>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

The config.php file:

```
    $cas_server = "localhost:8081";
    $cas_port = 443;
    $cas_context = "/cas-server-webapp-3.6.0";
    $cas_ac_path = "auth_cas/certificat/cert.pem" ;
    $applicationExitURL = "authorized/login.php";
```

Comment: Post the CAS related properties, every single one you used to configure the CAS module.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil I added the content of config.php